# Apple Mach-O Linker Error for adding iAd Banner in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, iad

Trying to add iAd Banner view in app with the following code:

```
adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, -50);
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
adView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

It is giving Apple Mach-O Linker Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
"_CGRectOffset", referenced from:
  -[ContainerViewController viewDidLoad] in ContainerViewController.o
"_CGRectZero", referenced from:
  -[ContainerViewController viewDidLoad] in ContainerViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

If anyone can guide what needs to be fixed to get rid of these Errors.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you're linking the CoreGraphics framework.